Farmers fight foreclosure, building burns to the ground
I'm looking for a film that is is most likely a 70s or 80s film.
A group of farmers (or a sect of some kind) refuse to give up their home/barn for some reason (probably foreclosure). The police and military get involved. There may be a scene with a half-track vehicle or something. In the end the building(s) are set on fire, but the farmers survive by taking refuge in a compartment found through a door in the floor.

Aside from the year, it sounds like it could be The Arizona Cowboy. 
In short it has ranchers facing foreclosure and people hiding from a posse in a cellar. There's no fire, but it sounds like there's dramatic scene involving a lit fuse and the smell of smoke. 
According to its imdb connections page, it was also one of the films used to make the 1976 country spoof/supercut Meanwhile, Back at the Ranch. 

This one is too old, unfortunately. And there is definitely a big fire.

The first thing to mind was Days of Heaven so I'll throw that out there even though each detail is a little off.  Sorry!
